# How to embed LLVM assembly or intrinsics in C program with Clang?

Tags: assembly, llvm, clang, embedding

C compilers allows to embed assembly code in a C program.

I am pretty sure that Clang should allow embedding LLVM assembly or intrinsic code in C program. How can I embed LLVM assembly in C code?

Comment: Yes, it *should* allow it. No, it does not do it yet, sorry.

Comment: Which intrinsics?  If you just want to use, say, ARM NEON intrinsics, [you can do that without resorting to inline assembly](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/arm-advanced-simd-neon-intrinsics-and.html).

Comment: @robmayoff This is what I meant: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#intrinsic-functions

Comment: @SK-logic is this still the case currently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now you can't.

You can, however, write an LLVM assembly function separately in its own file, mark it as `alwaysinline`, then compile it with the rest of your files - this should get you the same result. See [this related question on how to first compile your C files to IR and then link them together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778471/how-can-i-do-llvm-link-time-optimization).

You can even compile the files separately and make sure you perform [link-time optimization (LTO)](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html), should do the same thing.

Comment: @Jay the pass is still there and enabled by default: https://llvm.org/doxygen/AlwaysInliner_8cpp_source.html - and there is still no support for LLVM IR asm { ... }